# Why does Éléonore call Louise "Chibi-Louise"?

Tags: the-familiar-of-zero

In *Zero no Tsukaima*, when Louise's older sister, Éléonore, is first seen, she shouts, "Louise! Chibi-Louise!" She calls Louise this many times, as pictured below.

[image]

What does this expression mean, and why does Éléonore use it when the rest of Louise's family does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "Chibi" (ちび or チビ), means "short person" or a "small child".

Louise is the vertically challenged youngest sister in the family. So it makes perfect sense for her older sisters to poke fun at her with the name "Chibi-Louise". (or "short Louise")

Comment: Only Éléonore seems to use it, though. Is this because Cattleya respects Louise more?

Comment: Éléonore is the oldest sister. So the age (and size) difference would naturally be the greatest when they were still growing up.

Comment: Note that "Chibi" might have derogatory connotation, so I think rather than "poke fun", it might be insulting depending on the context.